# Beginner C++ programmer, confused over dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, vector

I am trying to create a class analogous to the built-in vector class in C++. I have tried to follow all the instructions in Walter Savitche's textbook, but just can't get it to work properly.

The code was written using the Code::Blocks IDE and compiled using the gcc compiler.

The thing I think I'm missing is the relationship between array parameters and a pointer that points to an array.
This is what I understand about normal variables:

```
int *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4, a;
a = 5; // variable  of type int with value 5
p1 = &a; // p1 now points to the value 5
p2 = p1; // p2 now also points to the value of a
p3 = new int; // p3 points to an anonamous variable of type int with undefined value
*p3 = *p1 // value of variable changed to the value of a, namely 5, but doesn't point to a
p4 = new int; // p4 points to an anonamous variable of type int with undefined value
*p4 = 5; // value of variable changed to  5
p4 = p1 // p4 now also points to the value of a
```

This is what I essentially don't understand about arrays and pointers that point to arrays

```
int *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4, a[3] = {4, 5, 6}; // a points to the first indexed element of the array, namely 4
p1 = a; // p1 points to the exactly the same thing as a
p2 = new int[3]; // p2 points to an array of base type int with undefined values
p2[0] = 8; // is this the correct usage? is p2 "dereferenced" 
p2[1] = 9;
p2[2] = 10;
p2[2] = p1[2]; // again is this correct? is the third element of the array pointed to by p2 now equal to 6?
*p3 = a // what does this mean?
p4 = new int[4]; // p4 points to an array of base type int with undefined values
p4[0] = p2[0]; 
p4[1] = p2[1];
p4[2] = p2[2];
p4[3] = 3
p2 = p4 // p2 now points to p4, but what happens to the array p2 was pointing to?
delete [] p2; // does this destroy the pointer and the array it is pointing to or just one or the other?
```

For completeness sake my class is defined as follows:

```
class VectorDouble
{
public:
    // constructors
    VectorDouble(); // default constructor
    VectorDouble(int init_count); // user specified
    VectorDouble(const VectorDouble& vd_object); // copy constructor
    // destructor
    ~VectorDouble();
    // accessors
    int capacity_vd(); // get max_count
    int size_vd(); // get amt_count
    double value_at(int index); // get value of "value" at index i
    // mutators
    void push_back_vd(double put_at_end); // insert new element at end of "value"
    void reserve_vd(int incr_capacity); // set max_count
    void resize_vd(int incr_size); // set amt_count
    void change_value_at(double d, int index); // set value of "value" at index i
    // overloaded =
    void operator =(const VectorDouble& vd_object_rhs);
    // other
    friend bool operator ==(VectorDouble vd_object1, VectorDouble vd_object2);
private:
    double *value; // pointer that points to array of type double
    int max_count; // the memory allocated to the array
    int amt_count; // the amount of memory in use
};
```

And the troublesome function is:

```
void VectorDouble::push_back_vd(double put_at_end)
{
    double *temp;
    if(amt_count == max_count)
        max_count += 1;
    temp = new double[max_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < amt_count; i++)
        temp[i] = value[i];
    amt_count += 1;
    temp[amt_count] = put_at_end;
    value = temp;
}
```

The member function just seems to insert 0.0 instead of the user input, I have no idea why...

In main:

```
VectorDouble vec1(10);
    double dd;

    cout << "Enter 3 doubles to vec1:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ": ";
        cin >> dd;
        vec1.push_back_vd(dd);
    }

    cout << "The variables you entered were:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << i << ": " << vec1.value_at(i) << endl;
```

I enter:

12.5
16.8
15.2

I get back:

0
0
0

I fixed it! Only problem is that the mistake was exceedinly simple. Sorry to waste everybodies time, but thanks to all, I did learn quite a lot!

The mistake was my placement of `amt_count += 1;`, I'm used to arrays indexed from 1 not zero (I have done a lot of coding in the R language). The corrected code with the memoery leak taken care of is:

```
void VectorDouble::push_back_vd(double put_at_end)
{
    double *temp;
    if(amt_count == max_count)
        max_count += 1;
    temp = new double[max_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < amt_count; i++)
        temp[i] = value[i];
    temp[amt_count] = put_at_end;
    amt_count += 1;
    delete [] value;
    value = temp;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you "can't get it to work"? What goes wrong?

Comment: A pointer **never** points to a *value*. It points to an *object*  (which has a value or is indeterminate, but never mind that), behind an object, nowhere (`nullptr`), or is indeterminate like any other uninitialized object.

Comment: your function `push_back_vd` is indeed leaking memory, you need to delete the space that was allocated previously. So you need to call `delete[] value;` before you do `value = temp` (but of course after you copy the old values)

Comment: "anonamous variable" - I assume you mean anonymous. C++ has no such thing. You created a heap variable

Comment: If I use `delete [] value;` won't this mess everything up since I will essentially be deleting a private member variable? Or is this action only happening in the scope of the member function?

Comment: @byrongibby I'm not sure I understand, `delete []` deallocates the memory that `value` is pointing to, it does not remove the symbol `value` or modify the value of the pointer. You can do `printf("pointer %p \n",(void *)value); delete [] value; printf("pointer %p \n",(void *)value);` and see that the output does not change

Comment: @PeterT: That's UB. If you de-allocate something, all pointers to it become *indeterminate*. And yes, that *can* bite you.

Comment: @PeterT: I thought it destroyed the pointer as well, I've edited the question to include `delete [] value;`. Thanks for the explanation, I now understand this concept a bit better, unfortunately the code still doesn't work in the way I expect it to. The only thing it can be is that there is some larger problem with my class (I suppose), I'm going to mull it over a bit more and see if I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: @byrongibby your remaining error is an off-by-one in `temp[amt_count] = put_at_end;` which should be `temp[amt_count-1] = put_at_end;` or you can move down the line that's incrementinf `amt_count` below this line.

Comment: @PeterT: thanks! I solved it and came back to see you had as well. Too bad I can't accept your answer for the rep, but thanks so so much. Really don't know how you can spot errors so quickly just from fragments of the class specification!

Comment: @PeterT: I wrote that in my answer an hour ago :(

Comment: @Lightness: sorry I overlooked your answer, didn't get want you meant by it's an overflow on the first read - was reading too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is what I understand about normal variables

All correct, with the caveat that I'd avoid the terminology "points to the value *x*"; you're pointing to the *object*, which in turn has value *x*.

> This is what I essentially don't understand about arrays and pointers that point to arrays

You're confusing pointers with arrays. In `int a[3]`, `a` is an array. It is not a pointer. It is an array.

`*p3 = a` isn't valid, so it means nothing.

> p2 now points to p4, but what happens to the array p2 was pointing to?

You've leaked it.

> // does this destroy the pointer and the array it is pointing to or just one or the other?

It destroys the thing you `new`'d, that the pointer is pointing to. i.e. the array

Otherwise all correct.

---

As for your vector implementation, the main problem is that `temp[amt_count]` is an overflow because you've already incremented `amt_count`. Also, vector implementations typically grow exponentially rather than on-demand. Finally, you're leaking the previous storage.

Comment: See my comment above. Not "all correct". (Better, though I don't think strong enough. It's a basic confusion of different concepts.)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Which part of your comment did I not address in this answer?

Comment: (After your correction) I just think there's a crucial difference between terminology which is (just) obviously wrong and terminology which hints at a basic mis-understanding of the concepts involved, and calls for clearly explaining the concepts.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What correction? I just added information about the vector implementation. You never wrote a comment about the vector implementation. You're being weird :/

Comment: You corrected the first point, it was simply "All correct." before my first comment. I just don't think you went far enough there. And of yourse I'm weird.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Waaaaaaay before your first comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Using different terminology might help you:

A pointer is just an ordinary variable. Instead of holding an integer, a float, a double, etc., it holds a memory address. Consider the following:

```
int* p = nullptr; // p has the value "nullptr" or null memory address
int i = 5;        // i has value 5

p = &i;           // p now has the value of the address of i
```

The ampersand gets the *address* of a variable.

An asterisk *dereferences* a pointer; that is it will get the value stored in the memory address the pointer holds:

```
cout << *p << endl; // Prints whatever is stored in the memory address of i; 5
```

As for your vector implementation, try moving this line `amt_count += 1;` to below this line:
`temp[amt_count] = put_at_end;`, as you're trying to access beyond the end of your array.

---

### Most of your understanding is correct. But...

```
a[3] = {4, 5, 6}; // a points to the first indexed element of the array, namely 4
```

Although arrays and pointers can be indexed and treated in a similar fashion, they are different, and their differences can lead to some sneaky bugs; so be careful with this statement.

```
*p3 = a // what does this mean?
```

This is invalid. Your types don't match: *p3 is an integer, a is an array.

```
p2 = p4 // p2 now points to p4, but what happens to the array p2 was pointing to?
```

The array p2 was pointing to is now leaked memory. This is bad.

```
delete [] p2; // does this destroy the pointer and the array it is pointing to or just one or the other?
```

The value of the pointer does not change. However, the memory it points to is deallocated, so dereferencing it will give you undefined results. It's best to set `p2 = nullptr;` after deleting it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898068/what-happens-at-a-hardware-level-when-i-access-an-element-of-an-array/26898789#26898789) might help with your understanding of arrays and accessing their elements.

Comment: You missed a few issues (and suggested that they are not issues), but otherwise this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is really wrong...

```
void VectorDouble::push_back_vd(double put_at_end)
{
    double *temp;
    if(amt_count == max_count)
        max_count += 1;
    temp = new double[max_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < amt_count; i++)
        temp[i] = value[i];
    amt_count += 1;
    temp[amt_count] = put_at_end;
    value = temp;
}
```

Notice that in each call you allocate new array (even if there's still space), copy everything in it and leak memory (old array)...

Here is a slightly corrected version, but it's not guaranteed to be completely OK (;

```
void VectorDouble::push_back_vd(double put_at_end)
{
    if(amt_count == max_count)
    {
        max_count += 1;
        double *temp = new double[max_count];
        for(int i = 0; i < amt_count; i++)
            temp[i] = value[i];
        delete[] value;
        value = temp;
    }
    value[amt_count] = put_at_end;
    amt_count += 1;
}
```

Comment: This still allocates on every call if you didn't delete elements in the meantime. Typically a vector implementation grows exponentially. Also `value[amt_count]` is an overflow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Well, that's only slightly corrected version of what the author has (; I'm not going to do his ENTIRE homework (; The assignment is not an overflow - the allocated memory block has `amt_count + 1` elements using initial value of `amt_count`, so exactly "one more" for the new element. That's also exactly as the author had it - I only fixed the leaking part and useless allocation if there is space left.

Comment: _" the allocated memory block has amt_count + 1 elements using initial value of amt_count"_ What initial value is that? He didn't show one, and `0` is the only initial value that makes sense. (And if it started at `1` as you suggest, then now your `for` loop is wrong as it does not copy all of the data.) Starting at `0`, your code and the OP's code overflows every time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - ok, I see the problem now, I'll edit the answer a bit. ... done, I just put the increment of amt_count at the end, I guess it's fine now (;

Answer (score 0):

"p2 now points to p4, but what happens to the array p2 was pointing to?"

It is 'leaked', this means its still allocated but there is no way to reach it anymore. If you keep doing this is the same program your memory size will keep growing

Other languages (Java, c#,...) have 'garbage collectors' that detect when this happens and will free the memory automatically

C++ solution to this problem is to never user naked arrays and pointers. Instead you use std::vector and std::shared_ptr; these will clean up for you

Comment: The C++ standard has basic support for running with a GC (strict pointer derivation and those GC-macros for registering additional roots and such-like). It's just seldom used at all. See `[util.dynamic.safety]`